# automate libs versions in tycho manifest.mf

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, tycho, manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: XYZ Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: xyz-plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 4.0
Bundle-Vendor: XYZ
Automatic-Module-Name: XYZ-plugin
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8

Require-Bundle:
// bundles here

Bundle-ClassPath: 
libs/xyz-file-4.0.jar
```

Instead of mentioning 4.0 here , I want to take from Bundle-Version which is already 4.0

When bundle version changes to 5.0, xyz-file jar should change to libs/xyz-file-5.0.jar

Is there anyway to do it in manifest itself or any option to do using property file

Comment: In the Maven Tycho build you might run a `maven-antrun-plugin` in the `process-resources` phase for that. But it's recommended not to use a `Bundle-ClassPath` for embedding a JAR, since this will result to a JAR nested in a JAR (`xyz-file-4.0.jar` should be a separate bundle/plugin instead).

Comment: It might be easier to remove the version from the jar name instead of updating the manifest.